# Minimal polynomial of block matrix

Tags: matrices, minimal-polynomials, block-matrices

I'm trying to prove that the minimal polynomial of a diagonal block matrix i.e. a matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
       B & 0           \\[0.3em]
      0 & C       \\[0.3em]
     \end{bmatrix}$

is the less common multiple of the minimal polynomials of matrix B and matrix C.

Well I checked down the answer that the user @AndreasCaranti gave here:

[Minpoly and Charpoly of block diagonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433210/minpoly-and-charpoly-of-block-diagonal-matrix)

However there is a crucial aspect of the proof that I would like to have some clarification please:

- "the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $A$ vanishes when computed on each block do the minimal polynomial $m_i(x)$ of the $i$-th block divides $m(x)$". Why? Is this a property of block matrices? Why does the minimal polynomial of each block divides the matrix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{F}[X]$, we have

$$ p \begin{pmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} p(B) & 0 \\ 0 & p(C) \end{pmatrix}. $$

Since $m_A(A) = 0$, we have $m_A(B) = 0, m_A(C) = 0$ which implies that $m_B, m_C | m_A$.

Comment: Hi! Just a quick question $m_C|m_A$ means $m_C$ divides $m_A$, i suppose?

Comment: @GrangerObliviate Yep.

Comment: Hello @Granger Obliviate why is $p(0)=0$ ? (It seems trivial but i can't see why)

Comment: Can someone please answer..